# how to join excel data with stream analytics data in power bi

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

In one end I am sending a single table to power bi from stream analytics using the query

```
SELECT DeviceId, SignalCode, MeasurementTime INTO receivedsignalcodes FROM inputeventhub
```

And on the other hand I am uploading a table with some specific signal codes which indicate a fault into the power bi.

Input from these two sources are becoming seperate datasets in powerbi. My question is if there is anyway to join these two tables and see which signals that I received in stream analytics are in excel fault codes table inside powerbi.

I am open to any suggestions like writing a new stream analytics query but it gives error if i reuse the power bi output again in same query.
Or I can upload my excel file to azure storage to reuse it that way but it seems like power bi does not support blob storage yet.

Answer (score 1):

We're looking at how to make it more flexible, but as you note today the data would go to separate data sets and you'd not be able to join directly across them in the web ui.

You can follow two solution paths: 
Optimize for analytics:
You'd output the Stream Analytics output to Azure SQL. Then pull the data into Excel from there. You'll then be able to do the data mashup the way you'd like.

Optimize for real time:
Within stream analytics, join the data and ensure the output query includes all the reference data in the data set that is pushed into Power BI.

HTH, 
Lukasz

Comment: Any update on this after 18 months? Can I expect to output Stream Analytics output to the same dataset as static reference data, so I can properly model e.g. a hierarchy in SQL or Excel and combine that with the real-time data?

Comment: Do you by the way plan to include SQL database as input to stream analytics? This might some how solve the problem.